# Currency symbol is changed when I moved to second page in RDLC Report

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, rdlc

I have created one RDLC report and bind dataset from code behind.

 There are `more than 2 pages`in Report Viewer. I have set currency format and `Symbol as 'Rs'` in my system's *Regional and Language Option*.

My report is loaded successfully with all fields have Currency symbol as **'Rs'**, But when I moved down by my cursor or change page number to another page then currency symbol changed automatically into **Dollar($)** symbol.

I don't know how this is possible and how to resolve that if I want Rupee (Rs ) as currency symbol in report? 
Please Help!!! Thanks in Advance.

**NOTE:** When I exported report in pdf document, It displays currency symbol $ in all pages.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Placeholder Properties->Set Number & Date formatting options

[image]

[image]

Check this:

Set the "Language" report properties according to your regional requirements.

[Number or Currency in rdlc report](http://www.tyrodeveloper.com/2012/04/number-or-currency-in-rdlc-report.html)

[Adding Style and Formatting to a Report](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252080%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Please tell me, which language or format I have to put over there for Rupee (Rs ) currency?

Comment: thanks I had already tried this, But still conditions remains same when I moved down to second page of report it will displays currency $, that's because the **Current regional settings** of system is English(United States), You can watch this in last line of your uploaded image. So please focus on that and provide me a solution.

Comment: Just change the languague of your report as [showed in this image](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-g4tNK26EGvo/T4Xn02ob8SI/AAAAAAAAAGM/touHdQOTysI/s1600/properties.jpg)